# autocomplete with inline variable setting

Tags: bash, osx, environment-variables, autocomplete

I use 
bash version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0)
on my Mac with MacOS (10.13.6)

For example, I have autocomplete set up for the AWS CLI, via

`complete -C '/Users/jstoner/Library/Python/3.7/bin/aws_completer' aws`

in my .bashrc.

It works when I `aws ec2 descr...`, but it doesn’t do anything when I `AWS_PROFILE=xxx aws ec2 descr...` I've confirmed the same behavior with git autocomplete.

I'm sure it **should** work. Why would this be broken?

Comment: My aws autocompletion works fine with an environment variable set (macOS 10.14.1, Bash 4.4.23, bash-completion@2/2.8, and `aws` completion is set to `complete -C '/usr/local/bin/aws_completer' aws`, where `aws_completer` is a symlink to `../Cellar/awscli/1.16.60/bin/aws_completer`.